# Rails: Save country_select to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, country

I’m working on a form where user can pick country and there choice will be shown and show.html.erb.

I have added country_select in my form like this

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.country_select :country %>
 </div>
```

My model article.rb looks like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    has_many :article_article_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :article_article_categories

    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 500 }
    validates :author_id, presence: true

    attr_accessor :country
end
```

The select works and the user can select country.. Perfect!

But it won’t show up in my view/show.html.erb.. I have tried like this:

```
<%= @article.country %>
```

So therefor I generated a migration:

```
class AddCountryToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :article, :country, :string
  end
end
```

And ran the migration.

In my controller I added this to my params:

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:country, :title, :description, article_article_categories_ids: [])
end
```

But I get nothing.. 
At country_select documentation, under usage:
"Simple use supplying model and attribute as parameters:
country_select("user", "country")"

But I don’t really know, where to put that line of code..
I have tried to put it in my create, show, and params.. And updated with (“article”, "country")

Can someone help me to get a step closer? 
I also devise installed.. Maybe that could cause some trouble?
I'm working with rails 5.0.0

Comment: why are you defining `country` as `attr_accessor`?what you are saying indicates `country` is not saved properly, checking rails log to see if its param is passed through controller will be helpful

Comment: Does it actually persist the country? check in your rails console (`rails console`) with: `Article.pluck(:country)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of `attr_accessor :country` as **attr_accessor is used to define an attribute for object of Model which is not mapped with any column in database.**

To answer your question "*But I don’t really know, where to put that line of code.. I have tried to put it in my create, show, and params..* "

You have to put that line of code in your form view. The first attribute is the name of the model (article in your case) and the second is the name of your attribute (country in your case). You have already properly done this however with:

`<%= f.country_select :country %>`

You have to make sure that this form is actually for an `Article` so it should be:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <div>
  <%= f.country_select :country %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Haha.. Jesus. Yeah, you're absolutely right. Get rid of attr_accessor.
I did it because my select wouldn't work if I didn't. So I checked the model at github. Everything works now. Have no idea why it didn't in the first place. 
Thanks a lot!